# React APP with Laravel Back End, Can not Insert data

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, eloquent, insert

I'm learning to build React JS WebApp with Laravel Back End. I have problem when try to insert data, it seems my insert function in controller is not being called whatever method I try. Here is the code;

**The JS:**

```
fetch( '/api/links/', {
        method:'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(link)
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            //update the state of links
        });
```

**The /routes/api.php:**

```
Route::post('links', 'LinksController@store');
```

**The /app/Http/Controllers/LinksController.php:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $link = new Link;
    $link->title = 'Hard Coded Just For Testing';
    $link->url = 'http://but.still/not-inserted-to-database/';
    $link->save();
    return response()->json(null, 200);
}
```

My expectation there should be a new record in my Links table, but nothing new inserted.

What did I Miss?? Please Help.

UPDATE:
Event though I set the method to post in fetch options, it turns out when I observe in Developer tools - network tabs, it strangely change to GET method, that's why it never get to call my store function to insert data. Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: That all looks correct. Try some logging, such as `Log::info(__FUNCTION__);` at the top of your function, and `Log::info($link);` after you save it. Check in `storage/logs` to see what gets logged.

Comment: HI anyber, where should I put those code? is it in the store function in controller?

Comment: Correct. The first log would go right above `$link = new Link;`, the second right after `$link->save();` and before the return statement.

Comment: Done that, and after running the code, I've checked the storage/logs/laravel.log file, its Empty..

Comment: It seems my guess is right the store function is not being called at all, hmm I wonder why..?

Comment: Watch your browser console's network tab to see the path it's accessing, the method, and what the response is.

Comment: when I load the page there is one warning(Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://dec-key.rl/js/app.js
Source Map URL: bootstrap.js.map) in console log, but when I click the button to execute the insert, nothing added in console log, just the same as the first I load the page.

Comment: Update as I observe from the network tab of developer tool, the JS code did POST and call the API, but it turns out that it call the wrong method, so instead of calling store method in LinksController, it call the index method in LinksController.... hmm I wonder why, I mean there is nothing wrong with the routing..

Comment: Update again: as I further observe the network tabs, strangely the request header method changed from POST to GET that is why it call the function index (Route through GET), instead of the function store (Route through POST). So the question become what causing the request header method strangely changed itself, and how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
It turns out that because of extra '/' at the end of fetch URL, while in routes/api.php the URL does not have '/' at the end of it, that causing a reroute when original call to /api/links/ with POST rerouted to /api/links with GET. SO simply match the URL perfectly from the route and from the fetch, solve the problem.